# My contrast does not appear to be sticking...?

Tags: r, anova

I asked a question a while back but have attempted to amend so that it is slightly more succinct. I am attempting to run some contrasts but everytime I try to run the contrast, it does not appear to stick. I am wondering about whether it is something to do with my conditionfactor? Would anyone be able to help me out?

```
connection <- "C:/Users/Aiden/Downloads/FinalData.csv"

rawdat <- read.csv(connection, skip=2, header=F, sep=",")

# rawdat2 <- read.csv(connection) #not run; read_csv() is faster
rawdat3 <- read_csv(connection) 
#some variable names might contain brackets or plus signs. replace with dots
names(rawdat3) <- gsub("\\(|\\)|\\+", "\\.", names(rawdat3))
names(rawdat) <- names(rawdat3); rm(rawdat3) 
data <- rawdat #original dataset without reversing reverse coded items

###########################################################################
#Beginning analysis
#Finding those who passed the manipulation check and creating groups
#happy
happy <- filter(data, condition == 'happy', Q1_1 > 3)

#sadness
sadness <- filter(data, condition == 'sad', Q1_2 > 3)

#angry
angry <- filter(data, condition == 'angry', Q1_7 > 3)


#neutral 
neutral <- filter(data, condition == 'neutral', Q1_6 > 3)

data <- rbind(happy,sadness,angry,neutral)
conditionfactor <- as.factor(data$condition)
data <- cbind(data, conditionfactor)

#########################################################################

model <- aov(Competent ~ condition, data =data)
c1 <- c(0,-1,0,1)
c2 <- c(-1,0,0,1)
c3 <- c(0,0,-1,1)
comps <- cbind(c1,c2,c3)
contrasts(data$conditionfactor)= comps
summary(model)
```

Results in:

```
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
condition     3  15.34   5.115   4.754 0.00353 **
Residuals   130 139.88   1.076
```

As you can see, the contrast does not appear to have worked, despite not resulting in any errors?

Comment: You do not use conditionfactor in the model. And I think you need to define the contrasts before fitting the model.

Comment: It is not clear on what you are asking.  Without a sample of your data, one cannot begin to understand what is or is not the correct answer.  Since the anova was performed before the contrast function was called, there is not expectation that it should work.